# Android - notification repeats after opening activity

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm trying to build application which will send notification daily at specific time.. I'm using ***.setOngoing(true)*** and ***.setAutoCancel(true)*** because I want to stick notification unless user open application by tapping on notification. but when application opens notification disappears and show again after few seconds.. how to stop showing notification when open application but only at specific time?

**MainActivity code is:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

**AlarmReceiver Class is :**

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText("notification text")
            .setContentTitle("notification title")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true);
    notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());

}
```

}

Comment: Why have you used `.setAutoCancel(true)` while you can cancel the notification using `notification_id`, that is 100 in you code?

Comment: the problem is not to cancel the notification but notification appears again after few seconds how can i stop appearing it again?

Comment: I did trying canceling notification using notification id but notification appears again.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mainactivity put this code:-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

if(calendar.getTimeInMillis()>System.currentTimeMillis()){

     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent); //Repeat every 24 h


 }
else{

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Always set value with greater than current time",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and change the code on reciever look like this:-

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("STARTED_BY_RECEIVER", true);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText("notification text")
                .setContentTitle("notification title")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true);
        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
```

Try this!!

Comment: notification not appearing again.. also not opening application after tapping on notification. I need to open application by tapping on notification

Comment: i'm glad you helping me.. now first time if i open application by tapping on notification, notification disappears and application opened and notification  does not appears again.. but if i open application then again notification appears after few seconds

Comment: So how you want?means as per your requirement i already do this. but when you closed down the application and reopen you get notification because alarm alerted you for time set you.

Comment: Notification should appears at defined time only.. not when open application.. i already mention that in my question..

Comment: any help @sagar potdar?

Comment: So it should be one time alarm .its not repeating .It will alert you because your set time value is already done thats why it will alert you.alarm manager notify you for the given time.

Comment: You got skype? so we can discuss this?